# DNS hosts, is my resdns registrations correct?

Tags: domain-name-system

I was wonderng of my dns registration are correct, to redirect `*.mydns.com` and `mydns.com` on the ip.

```
* 300 IN A 168.63.121.119
forum 300 IN A 168.63.121.119
web 300 IN A 168.63.121.119
www 300 IN A 168.63.121.119
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DNS doesn't do redirection, but if you're asking if your config will point `*.mydns.com` to your IP, then yes, it should. To simplify things, though, you could just get rid of the forum, web, and www `A` records, as those will be matched by the wildcard record.

Comment: I also need to point `mydns.com` to this ip, is that also good ?

Comment: No, for that, you'll need `@ 300 IN A 168.63.121.119`. Also, consider increasing your TTL. There's no need for you to set it to 300 unless you're going to be changing that record quite frequently.

Comment: I'm quiet a noob in these configuration, apache virtualhost and so on.
I prefer keep ttl low for that reason ! 
Thank's you !

Comment: DNS TTL has no bearing on your VHost configuration.

Comment: I know it too.. Just to say i'm a noob in networking, so i make many mistakes. A big ttl = bigger mistakes ..

Comment: A last ask : Is the dns registration orders important ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd just have the following entries:

```
mydns.com. IN A 168.63.121.119
*.mydns.com. 3600 IN CNAME mydns.com.
```

The wildcard CNAME redirects to mydns.net. Some recommend to use a seperate A entry for www too.